# How to pass parameter to shellscript in Dockerfile

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:11.15-slim
ARG ENV
WORKDIR /usr/src/project
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/project
COPY ./release /usr/src/project/
RUN npm install -g pm2 && npm install
EXPOSE 8888
RUN echo $ENV
RUN echo $ENV
RUN echo $ENV
RUN echo $ENV
CMD sh start_run.sh $ENV
```

when execute the shellscript in this dockefile, the $ENV seems did not pass to shellscipt.

Answer (score 0):

Rename variable ENV.
Or add new variable

```
ENV variable=$ENV
CMD sh -c 'echo $variable'
```